# Android Recyclerview lag while scrolling down

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, lag

I have a fragment with a recyclerview (GridlayoutManager) inside. The items in the recyclerview are not complicated or have images but while scrolling down the recyclerview lags (tested on a Nexus 5). I set hasFixedSize and hasStableIds to true
Has anyone an idea why this happens? 
Thanks in advance.

Fragment

```
public class EditTimetableFragment extends Fragment implements TimetableRecyclerViewAdapter.ClickListener {

public EditTimetableFragment() {}

DAO dao;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

RecyclerView recyclerViewTimetable;
Spinner spinnerSubject;
TimetableRecyclerViewAdapter timetableRecyclerViewAdapter;
TaskSubjectSpinnerAdapter taskSubjectSpinnerAdapter;
List<Subject> subjectList;
List<Timetable> timetableList;
FloatingActionButton fabAddSubject;
boolean saturday, sunday;
int dayLength, hourLength;
TextView textViewSa, textViewSu;
LinearLayout week, linearLayout;
View view;


public View getView() {
    return view;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this
    dao = new DAO(getActivity());
    getTimetableSettings();
    subjectList = dao.getAllSubjectsAlphabetical();
    timetableList = dao.getTimetableList(dayLength, saturday, sunday);

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit_timtable, container, false);

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"onCreateView",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    linearLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    fabAddSubject = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fabAddSubject);
    fabAddSubject.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), AddSubjectActivity.class));
        }
    });

    textViewSa = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewSa);
    textViewSu = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewSu);
    week = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.week);
    setRecyclerViewTimetable(view);
    setSpinnerSubject(view);

    if (saturday && sunday) {
        textViewSa.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        textViewSu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else if (saturday && !sunday) {
        textViewSa.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        textViewSu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else if (!saturday && sunday) {

        textViewSa.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        textViewSu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else if (!saturday && !sunday) {

        textViewSa.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        textViewSu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    return view;
}

public void setRecyclerViewTimetable(View view) {
    recyclerViewTimetable = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewTimetable);
    timetableRecyclerViewAdapter =
            new TimetableRecyclerViewAdapter(
                    getActivity(), true, saturday, sunday, dayLength);
    timetableRecyclerViewAdapter.setClickListener(this);
    recyclerViewTimetable.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerViewTimetable.setLayoutManager(
            new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), dayCount()));
    recyclerViewTimetable.setAdapter(timetableRecyclerViewAdapter);
}

private void setSpinnerSubject(View view) {
    spinnerSubject = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinnerSubject);
    taskSubjectSpinnerAdapter = new TaskSubjectSpinnerAdapter(getActivity(), subjectList);
    spinnerSubject.setAdapter(taskSubjectSpinnerAdapter);
}

private void getTimetableSettings() {
    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    saturday = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(getResources().getString(R.string.settingSaturday), false);
    sunday = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(getResources().getString(R.string.settingSunday), false);
    dayLength = sharedPreferences.getInt(getResources().getString(R.string.settingDay), 10);
    hourLength = sharedPreferences.getInt(getResources().getString(R.string.settingHour), 45);
    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "dayCount=" + dayCount() + " Sat" + saturday + " Sun" + sunday, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private int dayCount() {
    int a = 0;
    if (saturday && sunday) {
        a = 7;
    } else if (saturday && !sunday) {
        a = 6;
    } else if (!saturday && sunday) {
        a = 6;
    } else if (!saturday && !sunday) {
        a = 5;
    }
    return a;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getTimetableSettings();
    subjectList = dao.getAllSubjectsAlphabetical();
    timetableList = dao.getTimetableList(dayLength, saturday, sunday);

    setSpinnerSubject(view);
    setRecyclerViewTimetable(view);

    if (saturday && sunday) {
        textViewSa.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        textViewSu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else if (saturday && !sunday) {
        textViewSa.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        textViewSu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else if (!saturday && sunday) {
        textViewSa.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        textViewSu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else if (!saturday && !sunday) {
        textViewSa.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        textViewSu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

@Override
public void itemClicked(View v, int position) {
    timetableList = dao.getTimetableList(dayLength, saturday, sunday);
    subjectList = dao.getAllSubjectsAlphabetical();

    if (!subjectList.isEmpty()) {
        Timetable timetableOld = timetableList.get(position);
        Subject subject = subjectList.get(spinnerSubject.getSelectedItemPosition());
        Timetable timetableNew;
        if (timetableOld.getSubjectId().equals(subject.getId())) {
            timetableNew = dao.updateTimetable(timetableOld.getX(), timetableOld.getY(), "");
        } else {
            timetableNew = dao.updateTimetable(timetableOld.getX(), timetableOld.getY(), subject.getId());
        }
        timetableRecyclerViewAdapter.update(timetableNew, position);
    } else {
        Snackbar.make(linearLayout, R.string.AddSubjectsQuestion, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction(R.string.Yes, new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), AddSubjectActivity.class));
                    }
                }).show();
    }
  }
}
```

Layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1"
tools:context="com.feserware.learn.Timetable.EditTimetableActivity">

<include
    android:id="@+id/week"
    layout="@layout/week" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewTimetable"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="19dp">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinnerSubject"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabAddSubject"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        android:tint="#fff"
        app:fab_type="mini" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Adapter

```
public class TimetableRecyclerViewAdapter
    extends RecyclerView.Adapter
    <TimetableRecyclerViewAdapter.timetableViewHolder> {

List<Timetable> timetableList;
Context context;
ClickListener clickListener;
LayoutInflater inflater;
DAO dao;
boolean showHour, saturday, sunday;
int hours;

public TimetableRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, boolean showHour, boolean saturday, boolean sunday, int hours) {
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.context = context;
    dao = new DAO(context);
    this.timetableList = dao.getTimetableList(hours, saturday, sunday);
    this.showHour = showHour;
    this.saturday = saturday;
    this.sunday = sunday;
    this.hours = hours;
    setHasStableIds(true);
}


@Override
public timetableViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_timetable, parent, false);
    timetableViewHolder holder = new timetableViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(timetableViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Timetable timetable = timetableList.get(position);
    Subject subject = dao.getSubject(timetable.getSubjectId());
    holder.textViewTimetableSubjectShort.setText("");
    holder.textViewTimetableRoom.setText("");


    if (subject == null) {
        dao.updateTimetable(timetable.getX(), timetable.getY(), "");
    }

    if (timetable.getSubjectId().isEmpty()) {
        holder.textViewTimetableSubjectShort.setText(timetable.getY() + "");
        holder.linearLayoutBackground.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    } else {
        holder.textViewTimetableSubjectShort.setText(subject.getSubjectShort());
        holder.textViewTimetableRoom.setText(subject.getRoom());
        holder.linearLayoutBackground.setBackgroundColor(subject.getColor());
    }

}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return timetableList.size();
}

public void setClickListener(ClickListener clickListener) {
    this.clickListener = clickListener;
}

class timetableViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView textViewTimetableSubjectShort, textViewTimetableRoom;
    LinearLayout linearLayoutBackground;

    public timetableViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textViewTimetableSubjectShort = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewSubjectShort);
        textViewTimetableRoom = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewSubjectRoom);
        linearLayoutBackground = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutBackground);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (clickListener != null) {
            clickListener.itemClicked(v, getLayoutPosition());
        }
    }
}

public interface ClickListener {
    void itemClicked(View v, int postion);
}

public void update(Timetable timetable, int pos) {
    timetableList.set(pos, timetable);
    notifyItemChanged(pos);
  }
}
```

LogCat

```
 09-11 17:48:32.098  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TimetableRecyclerVH﹕ Constructor
09-11 17:48:32.148  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ timetableViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.148  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onCreateViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.156  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 0
09-11 17:48:32.159  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ timetableViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.159  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onCreateViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.165  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 1
09-11 17:48:32.169  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ timetableViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.170  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onCreateViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.175  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 2
09-11 17:48:32.178  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ timetableViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.178  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onCreateViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.184  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 3
09-11 17:48:32.188  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ timetableViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.189  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onCreateViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.195  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 4
09-11 17:48:32.203  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ timetableViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.203  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onCreateViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.209  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 5
09-11 17:48:32.211  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ timetableViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.211  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onCreateViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.217  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 6
09-11 17:48:32.222  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ timetableViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.222  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onCreateViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.228  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 7
09-11 17:48:32.231  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ timetableViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.231  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onCreateViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.237  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 8
09-11 17:48:32.239  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ timetableViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.239  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onCreateViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.246  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 9
09-11 17:48:32.252  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ timetableViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.252  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onCreateViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.259  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 10
09-11 17:48:32.261  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ timetableViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.261  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onCreateViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.264  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 11
09-11 17:48:32.266  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ timetableViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.266  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onCreateViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.269  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 12
09-11 17:48:32.272  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ timetableViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.272  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onCreateViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.276  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 13
09-11 17:48:32.278  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ timetableViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.278  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onCreateViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.281  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 14
09-11 17:48:32.288  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ timetableViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.288  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onCreateViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.292  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 15
09-11 17:48:32.320  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ timetableViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.320  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onCreateViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.326  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 16
09-11 17:48:32.328  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ timetableViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.328  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onCreateViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.333  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 17
09-11 17:48:32.335  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ timetableViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.335  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onCreateViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.342  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 18
09-11 17:48:32.344  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ timetableViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.344  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onCreateViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.349  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 19
09-11 17:48:32.358  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ timetableViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.358  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onCreateViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.367  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 20
09-11 17:48:32.370  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ timetableViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.370  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onCreateViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.376  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 21
09-11 17:48:32.378  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ timetableViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.378  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onCreateViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.383  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 22
09-11 17:48:32.385  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ timetableViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.385  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onCreateViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.393  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 23
09-11 17:48:32.395  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ timetableViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.395  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onCreateViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.400  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 24
09-11 17:48:32.422  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ timetableViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.422  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onCreateViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.430  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 25
09-11 17:48:32.432  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ timetableViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.432  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onCreateViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.437  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 26
09-11 17:48:32.443  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ timetableViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.443  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onCreateViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.450  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 27
09-11 17:48:32.456  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ timetableViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.457  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onCreateViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.464  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 28
09-11 17:48:32.466  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ timetableViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.466  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onCreateViewHolder
09-11 17:48:32.469  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 29
09-11 17:48:32.631  31535-31589/com.feserware.learn D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ endAllStagingAnimators on 0xa1b9ed00 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xa188dfb0
09-11 17:48:35.406  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ timetableViewHolder
09-11 17:48:35.406  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onCreateViewHolder
09-11 17:48:35.410  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 30
09-11 17:48:35.429  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ timetableViewHolder
09-11 17:48:35.429  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onCreateViewHolder
09-11 17:48:35.432  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 31
09-11 17:48:35.446  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ timetableViewHolder
09-11 17:48:35.446  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onCreateViewHolder
09-11 17:48:35.450  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 32
09-11 17:48:35.464  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ timetableViewHolder
09-11 17:48:35.464  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onCreateViewHolder
09-11 17:48:35.469  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 33
09-11 17:48:35.482  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ timetableViewHolder
09-11 17:48:35.483  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onCreateViewHolder
09-11 17:48:35.487  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 34
09-11 17:48:35.505  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 35
09-11 17:48:35.509  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 36
09-11 17:48:35.524  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 37
09-11 17:48:35.538  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 38
09-11 17:48:35.552  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ timetableViewHolder
09-11 17:48:35.552  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onCreateViewHolder
09-11 17:48:35.557  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 39
09-11 17:48:35.575  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 40
09-11 17:48:35.580  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 41
09-11 17:48:35.596  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 42
09-11 17:48:35.611  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 43
09-11 17:48:35.632  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ timetableViewHolder
09-11 17:48:35.632  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onCreateViewHolder
09-11 17:48:35.637  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 44
09-11 17:48:35.654  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 45
09-11 17:48:35.668  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 46
09-11 17:48:35.682  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 47
09-11 17:48:35.696  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 48
09-11 17:48:35.711  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 49
09-11 17:48:35.764  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 50
09-11 17:48:35.781  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 51
09-11 17:48:35.797  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 52
09-11 17:48:35.813  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 53
09-11 17:48:35.827  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ timetableViewHolder
09-11 17:48:35.827  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onCreateViewHolder
09-11 17:48:35.831  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 54
09-11 17:48:35.863  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 55
09-11 17:48:35.912  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 56
09-11 17:48:35.926  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 57
09-11 17:48:35.943  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 58
09-11 17:48:35.962  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 59
09-11 17:48:35.981  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 60
09-11 17:48:35.999  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 61
09-11 17:48:36.016  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 62
09-11 17:48:36.037  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 63
09-11 17:48:36.053  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ timetableViewHolder
09-11 17:48:36.053  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onCreateViewHolder
09-11 17:48:36.057  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 64
09-11 17:48:36.077  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 65
09-11 17:48:36.091  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 66
09-11 17:48:36.108  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 67
09-11 17:48:36.125  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 68
09-11 17:48:36.143  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 69
09-11 17:48:36.161  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 70
09-11 17:48:36.176  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 71
09-11 17:48:36.191  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 72
09-11 17:48:36.206  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 73
09-11 17:48:36.228  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ timetableViewHolder
09-11 17:48:36.228  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onCreateViewHolder
09-11 17:48:36.232  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 74
09-11 17:48:36.249  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 75
09-11 17:48:36.264  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 76
09-11 17:48:36.278  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 77
09-11 17:48:36.293  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 78
09-11 17:48:36.306  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 79
09-11 17:48:36.324  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 80
09-11 17:48:36.342  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 81
09-11 17:48:36.357  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 82
09-11 17:48:36.371  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 83
09-11 17:48:36.383  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ timetableViewHolder
09-11 17:48:36.383  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onCreateViewHolder
09-11 17:48:36.387  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 84
09-11 17:48:36.410  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 85
09-11 17:48:36.424  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 86
09-11 17:48:36.438  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 87
09-11 17:48:36.454  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 88
09-11 17:48:36.470  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 89
09-11 17:48:36.498  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-11 17:48:36.539  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 90
09-11 17:48:36.556  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 91
09-11 17:48:36.571  31535-31535/com.feserware.learn D/TtRecycler﹕ onBindViewHolder | 92
```

Comment: Could you do some benchmarking to see where your program is spending its time?

Comment: Can you also add the DAO class? I think the subject fetch could be a possible place.Is that a database query? or just a normal pojo

Answer (score 1):

Ok I do not know what exactly is wrong with your code but what I can do is provide you with a sample recycler code I use, am sure you can do a comparison with yours and figure our where you might be going wrong, it is an expandable recycler with the child having a horizontal listview with images in it, I do not experience lags I use a huawei Y300, thats a low end phone, i chose that phone bacause i knew if my code would work great on it then it would on most phones so here is a sample of my Expandable recycler adapter, my code though suffers from memory usage it shoots to about 20mb after loading about 20 items each with 5 images

```
public class ExpandableCategoryAdapter extends ExpandableRecyclerAdapter<CategoryParentViewHolder, CategoryChildViewHolder> {
/**
 * Primary constructor. Sets up {@link #mParentItemList} and {@link #mItemList}.
 * <p>
 * Changes to {@link #mParentItemList} should be made through add/remove methods in
 * {@link ExpandableRecyclerAdapter}
 *
 * @param parentItemList List of all {@link ParentListItem} objects to be
 *                       displayed in the RecyclerView that this
 *                       adapter is linked to
 */
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private CategoryChildViewHolder childViewHolder;
private Context context;
private UserDataHolderDB db;

//click onitemlisteners
//I chose these because they
//readily provide the IDS/position
private OnItemClickListener addItemListener;
private OnItemClickListener gotoListener;
public ExpandableCategoryAdapter(OnItemClickListener addItemListener,  OnItemClickListener gotoListener,Context context, ArrayList<ExpandableCategoryItem> parentItemList) {
    super(parentItemList);
    this.addItemListener = addItemListener;
    this.gotoListener = gotoListener;
    this.context = context;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    db = new UserDataHolderDB(context);
}

//ofcos the interface to implement from
public interface OnItemClickListener {
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}

@Override
public CategoryParentViewHolder onCreateParentViewHolder(ViewGroup parentViewGroup) {
    View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.parent_category, parentViewGroup, false);
    return new CategoryParentViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public CategoryChildViewHolder onCreateChildViewHolder(ViewGroup childViewGroup) {
    View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.cloth_min_adapter, childViewGroup, false);
    return new CategoryChildViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindParentViewHolder(CategoryParentViewHolder parentViewHolder, int position, ParentListItem parentListItem) {
    parentViewHolder.setIsRecyclable(true);
    ExpandableCategoryItem parentData = (ExpandableCategoryItem) parentListItem;
    parentViewHolder.mCrimeTitleTextView.setText(parentData.getmDescription());

    try {
        System.err.println("Palette value: " + parentData.getmSideBarColor());
        if (parentData.getmSideBarColor() != null) {
            parentViewHolder.mSideBar.setBackgroundColor(Integer.parseInt(parentData.getmSideBarColor()));
            parentViewHolder.mSideBar.invalidate();

        }
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("Palette value could not be decoded");
    }

    if(!parentViewHolder.isExpanded())
    {

            try{
                if(childViewHolder.linearLayout != null) {
                    childViewHolder.linearLayout.removeAllViews();

                    if(parentData.getmSideBarColor() != null)
                    {

                        if(parentData.getmSideBarColor().isEmpty())
                        {

                        }

                    }
               // parentViewHolder.mSideBar.getBackground() =
                }
            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        //trash child to save memory

    }

    try {
        //reduce bitmap size to save on memory
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(parentData.getmCategoryImgPath());
        bitmap = ResizeImage.getResizedBitmap(bitmap, 100, 100);
        parentViewHolder.mCategoryImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    /
    System.err.println("Parent ID"+parentData.getId());
    System.err.println("Parent Description at Given ID: "+parentData.getmDescription());

    parentViewHolder.mItemsShow.setText(db.categoryItemsNumber(parentData.getId()));
}

@Override
public void onBindChildViewHolder(CategoryChildViewHolder childViewHolder, int position, Object childListItem) {


    //Button being assigned the Listener
    childViewHolder.gotTo.setOnClickListener(v -> gotoListener.onItemClick(v, position));
    childViewHolder.addNewItem.setOnClickListener(v -> addItemListener.onItemClick(v, position));



    ChildItem data = (ChildItem) childListItem;
    this.childViewHolder = childViewHolder;
    int rootViewController = 0;

    try {
        childViewHolder.linearLayout.removeAllViews();
    }catch (Exception w)
    {
        w.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(data.getImgUri() != null) {

        for (String item : data.getImgUri()) {

            try {
                //stop adding images we are past our limit
                if (rootViewController != 5) {

                    if(item.equals("") || !item.isEmpty()) {
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(item);
                        bitmap = ResizeImage.getResizedBitmap(bitmap, 100, 100);
                        Bitmap bitmap2 = ImageCornerMoulder.getRoundedCornerBitmap(bitmap, calculatePercentage(5, bitmap.getHeight()));

                        //add images we still have enough space
                        rootViewController = (rootViewController + 1);
                        View rootView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.expandable_image_item, null);
                        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.clothItem);
                        rootView.setTag(new ImageObject(Uri.parse(item)));
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap2);
                        if(bitmap != bitmap2)
                        {
                            bitmap.recycle();
                        }

                        childViewHolder.linearLayout.addView(rootView, 0);

                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();


                //set default image
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.clothes);
                    bitmap = ResizeImage.getResizedBitmap(bitmap, 100, 100);
                    Bitmap bitmap2 = ImageCornerMoulder.getRoundedCornerBitmap(bitmap, calculatePercentage(5, bitmap.getHeight()));
                    //add images we still have enough space
                    rootViewController = (rootViewController + 1);
                    View rootView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.expandable_image_item, null);
                    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.clothItem);


                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    if(bitmap != bitmap) {
                        bitmap.recycle();
                    }
                    childViewHolder.linearLayout.addView(rootView, 0);


            }
        }

    }


        childViewHolder.linearLayout.invalidate();



}


private int calculatePercentage(int percentage, int target)
{
    int k = (int)(target*(percentage/100.0f));
    return k;

}

 }
```

how i use it

```
  adapter = new ExpandableCategoryAdapter(addItems,goTo,getBaseContext(),  data arraylist);
                        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getBaseContext()));
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Can you please post a sample project link. Or share your sample project on github.

Comment: it is not yet complete, you could point out what you are interested in then I can upload the files

Comment: I'm more interested in an example of simple recycler view with images that scrolls without any lag. Can u please provide me an example project.

Comment: not to worry, let me set it up and I will update you on the link stick around.

Comment: And then with all respect, we all will be very thankful to you. Because most of the users are experience this lagging problem in their recycler view when scrolling .

Comment: here is the link to the requested project components, I included the screenshots to have an overview of how it looks like, please if you find anything wrong inform me, or you make code changes that will work better inform me my app is still in progress I will like to integrate it in my app and please accept my answer if it works thanks

Comment: sorry https://github.com/aubryll/Sample-RecyclerView-with-Expandable-view-with-horizontal-scrollview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97042/discussion-between-rubin-nellikunnathu-and-life-evader).

Answer (score 0):

if you user Recyclerview in vertical mode and your activity contains other item that you have `ScrollView` then you must use `NestedScrollView` instead of `ScrollView`.

as described in google documentation NestedScrollView is just like ScrollView, but it supports acting as both a nested scrolling parent and child on both new and old versions of Android. Nested scrolling is enabled by default.

I'm sure using NestedScrollView will solve this issue.

Answer (score -1):

The class which extends ViewHolder class in adapter should be a static one. This would certainly improve the performance. You should edit your code as below.

Replace

```
class timetableViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements
View.OnClickListener
```

with

```
static class timetableViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
```

Comment: But if i need to get the position of recyclerview item to viewholder, then how .? when i change the onClick(View v) to onClick(View v, int pos) , it throws error.

Comment: Use getAdapterPosition() method. It will give you the current adapter position.